# Understanding polymorphism in C++

Tags: c++, polymorphism

I am trying to understand the mechanism of polymorphism in C++ using this simple example (constructors were written explicitly in hpp files for clarity, the same holds for public members)

Base  class:

```
//Base.hpp
#ifndef _Base_H_
#define _Base_H_
class Base{

    public:

    int BaseVar;

    Base():BaseVar(0){};
    int getBaseVar(){return BaseVar;}
    virtual int DoNothing(){return 0;};

};
#endif
```

Derived class

```
//Derived.hpp
#include "Base.hpp"
#ifndef _Derived_H_
#define _Derived_H_

class Derived: public Base{

   public:
   int DerivedVar;

   Derived():Base(),DerivedVar(0){};
   int getDerivedVar(){return DerivedVar;}
};

#endif
```

Polymorph class

```
//Polymorph.hpp
#include "Derived.hpp"
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
#ifndef _Polymorph_H_
#define _Polymorph_H_

class Polymorph{

    public:
    vector<Base *> PolyMorphVector;

    Polymorph(int VectorSize):PolyMorphVector(VectorSize)
    {

      for (int i(0);i<VectorSize;i++)
          PolyMorphVector[i]=new Derived;

    }

 };

#endif
```

Main program

```
//main.cpp
#include "Polymorph.hpp"

int main()
{
    int i;
    Polymorph *MyPolymorph = new Polymorph(10);
    i=MyPolymorph->PolyMorphVector[0]->getDerivedVar();//copmiler error: "'getDerivedVar' : is not a member of 'Base'" ... Oh, really?
    i=(dynamic_cast<Derived *>(MyPolymorph->PolyMorphVector[0]))->getDerivedVar();//OK!!
    return 0;
}
```

Everthing was compiled in VS 2010 with Win7 OS (64 bit).

1. Is the assignment:

   ```
   PolyMorphVector[i]=new Derived;
   ```

   considered as good practice?
2. Why do I have to dynamic_cast explicitly although I allocated each element of   PolyMorphVector with Derived class?

Comment: getDerivedVar is not declared in Base class. To be polymorphic, a method  should be declared in Base class as virtual

Comment: Oh to be back in those days when I was first learning and I'd get so frustrated my brain would just stop working entirely.

Comment: Come to think of it...that still happens :p

Comment: Polymorphism (the C++ object-oriented kind, there are also other kinds) is **calling virtual functions in derived objects through base class pointers or references**. No more, no less. `dynamic_cast<Derived*>(pBase)` is pretty much the opposite of polymorphism.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(1) The assignment will work but there's no explicit ownership anywhere, you'd be better off with something like

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Base>> poly_morph_vector;
```

and then initializing by

```
for (auto& b : poly_morph_vector) {
     b = std::make_unique<Derived>();
}
```

(2) `Base` has no member function by that name so you get a compile time error.  If you want dynamic dispatch you'd need something like

```
class Base {
 public:
  virtual int get_var() const { return base_var; }
};

class Derived : public Base {
 public:
  int get_var() const override { return derived_var; }
};
```

then your code to get the variable becomes

```
auto i = MyPolymorph->poly_morph_vector.front()->get_var();
```

Comment: Yes, but each element of PolyMorphVector actually holds Derived and not Base.

Comment: @BennyK that is correct. meh, sort of. The vector holds `pointers` only. What is actually being pointed to may differ

Answer (score 2):

You didn't use any real polymorphism in your example. The idea of polymorphism is that a function provided by a derived class can be called from the interface defined by the base class. In particular, the interface can be used (calling the `virtual` methods) and implemented (defining a derived class) completely independently and yet it works.

```
struct base
{
    virtual int method1() const = 0;      // pure virtual: has to be overriden
    virtual int method2(int i) const      // defaults to base::method2()
    { return i*x; }
    base(int i) : x(i) {}
    virtual ~base() {}                    // derived can be destroyed from here
    const int x;
};

void print(const base*p)                  // using the interface
{
    std::cout << p->method1() << std::endl;
}

struct derived : base                     // providing an interface
{
    int method1() const override
    { return method2(x); }                // polymorphic call of foo::method2
    derived(int i): base(i), x(i+i) {}
    const int x;
};

struct foo : derived                      // extending the interface again
{
    int method2(int i) const override
    { return i<<2; }
    foo(int i) : derived(2+i);
};

std::vector<unique_ptr<base>> pter;
for(int i=0; i!=10; ++i)
    pter.push_back(make_unique<foo>(i));  // unfortunately make_unique is C++14

for(auto const&p:pter)
    print(p.get());                       // calls foo::method1()
```

Note that the destructor of `pter` will call `base::~base()` which, being `virtual`, will call the destructor of `foo` (though in this example, it does nothing).